# Where to find a fake hierarchy for a honeypot for double-dot/path traversal attacks?

Tags: webserver, honeypot, path-injection

I would like to provide content when a hacker tries something like `GET /../../../etc/passwd`, but they may choose something else, other than `passwd`. I will install notification of when somebody does this, but in order to keep the hacker's attention in a fixed point for some time, I would like to have some fake data.

Does anyone have a suggestion on a starting point? All the data would be statically served, I was thinking maybe some linux directory structure, but preferably something more light weight. If there is something like this you are aware of, I would be interested. It does not need to be complete, just contain a bunch of files that would typically be found on a (web)server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a url rewrite rule mapping urls matching `../etc/*` (or some other expression) to `somevirtualdirectory/*` and place whatever you like in `somevirtualdirectory` to be served.

[Damn Small Linux](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/) would have your basic minimal [*nix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%2anix) folder hierarchy on live CD that you could copy over and lock down (remove execute permissions and such).

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear, but that is not what I am asking.  I am asking if you have a suggestion on a fake hierarchy I can copy to `somevirtualdirectory` so I don't have to start from scratch.

Comment: [Damn Small Linux](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/) would have your basic minimal *nix folder hierarchy on live CD that you could copy over and lock down (remove execute permissions and such).